# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling t.addCustomDisplayData

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, azure-databricks, kafka-consumer-api

What am i doing wrong here?

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DXCd.png)

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOXVT.png)

Comment: please share code snippet in code format.

Comment: df = (
    spark.read
        .format('kafka')
        .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', BOOTSTRAP_SERVER)
        .option('kafka.security.protocol','SASL_SSL')
        .option('kafka.sasl.mechanism','PLAIN')
        .option('kafka.sasl.jaas.config',f"{JAAS_MODULE} required username='{CLUSTER_API_KEY}' password='{CLUSTER_API_SECRET}';")
        .option('subscribe','invoices')
        .load()
    )

Comment: df = (spark.read
      .format('kafka')
      .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', BOOTSTRAP_SERVER)
      .option('kafka.security.protocol', 'SASL_SSL')
      .option('kafka.sasl.mechanism', 'PLAIN')
      .option('kafka.sasl.jaas.config', f'{JAAS_MODULE} required username="{CLUSTER_API_KEY}" password="{CLUSTER_API_SECRET}";')
      .option('subscribe', 'invoices')
      .load()
     )

Comment: Can you try the above?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481628/spark-structured-streaming-with-kafka-sasl-plain-authentication

Comment: Can you check the above SO link if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a Kafka connection with the options below:

```
options = {
    "kafka.sasl.jaas.config": 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="USERNAME" password="PASSWORD";',
    "kafka.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
    "kafka.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
    "kafka.bootstrap.servers": bootstrap_servers,
    "group.id": group_id,
    "subscribe": topic,
}
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").options(**options).load()
```

This code sets up the necessary configurations for connecting to a Kafka broker using the **SASL_SSL** security protocol with plain text credentials.
It then reads streaming data from the specified Kafka topic into a DataFrame df.

In production, it's recommended to store your **JAAS** config in a file named jaas.conf and remove the `kafka.sasl.jaas.config` option from your Spark application.
Instead, you should pass the file path to the spark-submit command using the --driver-java-options flag.

```
options = {
    "kafka.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
    "kafka.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
    "kafka.bootstrap.servers": bootstrap_servers,
    "group.id": group_id,
    "subscribe": topic,
}
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").options(**options).load()
```

For spark-submit, provide the file path to jaas.conf using --driver-java-options:

```
spark-submit \
  --driver-java-options -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/jaas.conf \
  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.5 yourapp.py
```

Make sure to adjust the file path and package versions according to your application's requirements.

**Reference:** [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481628/spark-structured-streaming-with-kafka-sasl-plain-authentication) link